# How to explicitly convert a MouseButtonEventArgs to an object that has .Tag

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I've turned `Option Strict` to `On` (Because I want to convert all this code from VB to C#) and there's this one situation I can't figure out. Here is a snippet of the code:

```vb
Private Sub MessageClicked(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    Dim obMenuItem = e.OriginalSource
    If obMenuItem.Tag IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim Message = MessageCollection.FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.ID = obMenuItem.Tag.ToString)
        If Message.Outbound = False AndAlso Message.ReadBy = "" Then MarkAsRead(SelectedTractor, obMenuItem.Tag.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

The error arises any time time I try to use `obMenuItem` after it's been declared. I know I need to initialize it using the `As` phrase, but I don't know what I'm supposed to initialize it as.

I tried `Object` and `MouseButtonEventArgs`, but neither of those have the `.tag` I'm trying to access.

Comment: If this is WPF, it is probably the `System.Windows.Controls.Control` class.

Comment: Try casting it to `MenuItem`. `MenuItem` has a tag, and the variable name `obMenuItem` seems to be a hint at the expected type of the object. Use `as` to cast, and check for null. But you can always put a breakpoint in there and hover the mouse over `e.OriginalSource` and discover the actual runtime type of the object.

Comment: How are you even calling this sub? There is no handle, so as is, it's not doing anything.

Comment: How is this c#?

Comment: are you sure it's c#? looks like VB to me.

Comment: Clearly she said she wants to convert her vb code to c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Tag` property is declared in the FrameworkElement class, so you need to perform the following type cast at least. Note that in case you need to access other propertyies of more derived classes, you must of course use a more derived target type for the cast:

```
Dim obMenuItem As FrameworkElement = CType(e.OriginalSource, FrameworkElement)
```

Instead of `e.OriginalSource` it seems also more appropriate to cast the `sender` object:

```
Dim obMenuItem As FrameworkElement = CType(sender, FrameworkElement)
```

Comment: There we go, this is what I needed. Thank you :)